# How to click on the element using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

https://shop.medtronic-diabetes.ch/

In above site, click on **Anmelden** link from top right, 3rd last.
I am not able to locate E-mail xpath since it is a part of frame.

Tried below but no luck

1. `driver.switchTo().frame(0);`
2. `driver.switchTo().frame("cbox1556878105885");`
3. `driver.switchTo().frame("cboxIframe");`
4. `driver.switchTo().frame(find_element_by_xpath(//xpath));`

Comment: Anmelden is not present on that given URL. Just check and update the URL. I'm getting `SYSTEM ERROR OCCURRED` exception

Comment: yes, system error for me as well

Comment: Updated url @cruisepandey, Adi Ohana.
Apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the element with text as **Anmelden** located at the top right which is the 3rd last item and then send a *character sequence* to the *Email* field, you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://shop.medtronic-diabetes.ch/");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("li.firstRow a[title='Anmelden']"))).click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe.cboxIframe")));
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.signInboxInputFields#j_username"))).sendKeys("Mohit_Garg");
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://shop.medtronic-diabetes.ch/");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[@class='firstRow']//a[text()='Anmelden']"))).click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='cboxIframe']")));
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='signInboxInputFields required' and @id='j_username']"))).sendKeys("Mohit_Garg");
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: medi]

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below locator.

```
     Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://shop.medtronic-diabetes.ch/");
     WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
     var loginElement = webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("div[class='registerNow firstChild'] a[title='Anmelden']")));
     loginElement.Click();
     webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.ClassName("cboxIframe")));
     var email = webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("j_username")));
     email.SendKeys("Rd@test.com");
```

The recommended way to switch to an iframe is using the webdriverwait - expected conditions like this `ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt`.
if you have an ID for the iframe, then use `Driver.SwitchTo().Frame("frameID");`

And to Selects either the first frame on the page or the main document, use `Driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();` or to Select the parent frame, use  `Driver.SwitchTo().ParentFrame();`

Comment: Apologies, my question was not that clear realized now. I actually wanted to have access to Email option in that login pop up.

Comment: @Mohit Garg I have edited the answer